# App using LWJGL can't find display mode extension on Linux

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm running LWJGL app on Ubuntu virtual machine with no phisical graphic card. I set up Xvfb and Mesa3D but it fails with exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.createPbuffer(Pbuffer.java:234) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.<init>(Pbuffer.java:219) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer.<init>(Pbuffer.java:190) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: No display mode extension is available
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:141) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: No display mode extension is available
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:724) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138) ~[lwjgl.jar:na]
```

App is running from cron using script

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority
xauth add localhost:1 . 11111111111111111111111111111111
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 -nolisten tcp
/home/username/start.sh
```

Most of steps above were adopted from [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Programs_and_Editors/Tectonicus/VPS#xvfb-run_script) but I'm not sure I did it correctly.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error when trying to run a LWJGL program remotely using VirtualGL. It can be reproduced with the GLGears demo from http://lwjgl.org/demos.php. For the test, I grabbed the files as follows:

```
wget http://lwjgl.org/webstart/{lwjgl_test,media}.jar
wget http://lwjgl.org/webstart/2.9.1/{lwjgl,lwjgl_util,jinput,native_linux}.jar
unzip native_linux.jar libjinput-linux64.so liblwjgl64.so
```

The command to run it over VGL:

```
vglrun java -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true \
    -Djava.library.path=$PWD \
    -cp $(echo *.jar | tr ' ' :) \
    org.lwjgl.test.opengl.Gears
```

This gives exactly the error you have:

```
Could not locate symbol glXEnumerateVideoDevicesNV
Could not locate symbol glXBindVideoCaptureDeviceNV
[LWJGL] Xrandr extension not available
[LWJGL] XF86VidMode extension not available
[LWJGL] No display mode extensions available
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.lwjgl.test.opengl.Gears.init(Gears.java:159)
        at org.lwjgl.test.opengl.Gears.execute(Gears.java:85)
        at org.lwjgl.test.opengl.Gears.main(Gears.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: No display mode extension is available
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:141)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: No display mode extension is available
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:724)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
        ... 3 more
```

The error comes from [src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/LinuxDisplay.java:199](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/LinuxDisplay.java#L199), it looks like it has something to do with mode extensions not being advertised by the X server:

```
private static int getBestDisplayModeExtension() {
    int result;
    if (isXrandrSupported()) {
        LWJGLUtil.log("Using Xrandr for display mode switching");
        result = XRANDR;
    } else if (isXF86VidModeSupported()) {
        LWJGLUtil.log("Using XF86VidMode for display mode switching");
        result = XF86VIDMODE;
    } else {
        LWJGLUtil.log("No display mode extensions available");
        result = NONE;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In my case, `ssh -Y user@host` instead of `ssh -X user@host` was enough to forward the RandR extension. Do this only if you trust the other host! According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693510/427545), you can enable RandR for Xvfb with:

```
Xvfb +extension RANDR [further options]
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the question. Only answers should be posted in the answers section; this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @JoshPetrie The answer already contained a hint, namely a mode-related issue. I've now updated it with a possible solution for OP. Hopefully you can understand that finding the root issue is one of the steps to solve a problem.

Comment: For those who use VirtualGL, be sure to set `VGL_PROBEGLX=0` to avoid `libGL error: failed to authenticate magic` errors. It otherwise occurs because to the `GLX` extension is exposed by clients which somehow cause VirtualGL to probe for the DRI extension on the client display (e.g. SSH's `localhost:13.0` instead of `:1`).